# appium cannot type in textfield

Tags: android, mobile, automated-tests, appium, nativescript

I'm using nativescript and nativescript-dev-appium to perform end to end tests and I'm trying to enter some text into a text field.

The textField in my xml layout;

```
      <StackLayout padding="10">
           <Label text="Date of Purchase"></Label>
           <DatePickerField hint="Select Date" [(ngModel)]="_dataItem.date_of_purchase"></DatePickerField>
      </StackLayout>

      <StackLayout padding="10">
        <Label text="Name"></Label>
        <TextField automationText="name" hint="Asset Name" [(ngModel)]="_dataItem.name" class="input">
        </TextField>
      </StackLayout>
```

My spec;

```
import { AppiumDriver, createDriver, SearchOptions, nsCapabilities } from "nativescript-dev-appium";
import { assert } from "chai";
const addContext = require('mochawesome/addContext');

describe("sample scenario", () => {
    let driver: AppiumDriver;

    before(async function(){
        nsCapabilities.testReporter.context = this; 
        driver = await createDriver();
    });

    after(async function () {
        await driver.quit();
        console.log("Quit driver!");
    });

    afterEach(async function () {
        if (this.currentTest.state === "failed") {
            await driver.logTestArtifacts(this.currentTest.title);
        }
    });

    it("should find an element by text", async function () {
        const nameField = await driver.findElementByAutomationText("name");
        await nameField.sendKeys("3d printer");

        const btnTap = await driver.findElementByAutomationText("create");
        await btnTap.click();
    });
});
```

Error I get;

```
Error: [element.sendKeys("3d printer")] Error response status: 12, InvalidElementState - An element command could not be completed because the element is in an invalid state (e.g. attempting to click a disabled element). 
Selenium error: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Cannot set the element to '3d printer'. 
Did you interact with the correct element? at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.SendKeysToElement.safeHandle(SendKeysToElement.java:97) at 
io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:37) at 
io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:252) at 
io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:243) at 
io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:44) at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366) at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345) at 
io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366) at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345) at 
io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435) at 
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) at 
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267) at 
io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250) at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366) at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345) at 
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294) at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366) at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) at 
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911) at 
io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131) at 
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611) at 
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552) at 
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438) at 
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140) at 
io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I've also tried nameField.type("3d printer") and get the same error.

**Update: Try Xpath**

```
it("should find an element by text", async function () {
    const nameField = await driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@automationText='name']");
    await nameField.click();
    await nameField.sendKeys("3d printer");
```

Got error

```
Error: [waitForElementByXPath("//*[@automationText='name']",5000)] Element condition wasn't satisfied!
```

**Update: find by class name 'textfield' works**

If I use the following in my test and the first text field which appears on the form is the name field then this works.

```
    const nameField = await driver.findElementByClassName(driver.locators.getElementByName("textfield"));
    await nameField.sendKeys("3d printer");
```

But how do I select the text field if it's not the first field?

Comment: Try change `.findElementByAutomationText` with find element by `xpath` with following value: `//*[@automationText='name']`. Before sendkey, click first.

Comment: Now it cannot find the element at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had to use findElementByAccessibilityId like so;

```
    const nameField = await driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("name");
    await nameField.sendKeys("2");

    const btnTap = await driver.findElementByAutomationText("create");
    await btnTap.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you try first clean the element, like myTextField.clean() and then sendKeys

Comment: I get the error TS2339: Property 'clean' does not exist on type 'UIElement'.